Is it possible to analyse this as time series data? What model should I use for this data?
I have a variable that goes from 1 to 10, where 1 is "never justifiable" and 10 is "always justifiable". The answers have high density at the extremes and in the middle (1, 10, 5, 6). This item also has a "don't want to answer" option. This question is collected from different people, but on the same countries, in 5 waves of the study.
I'd like to predict responses for this variable using 5 others, both categorical and numerical. The thing is, I don't know if it's possible to use linear regression, logistic regression, or if I need to switch to a machine learning model. Either way, it would be ideal if I could make statements about them as temporal data, but I think 5 data collections is less than any model needs.
So my questions are:

Is it possible to make statements about this data with only 5 data collections?
What model should I use given my 10 point item as the dependent variable?


Of course it is possible to do analyses on five waves of data. Whether that is more robust compared to 10 or 20 waves is debatable. The point is that you can still draw plenty of meaningful intuition from such data, provided there is enough there in terms of observations per time period and proper modeling of the data.
Since your data has an inherently ordinal structure and has limited responses per level, I think you could consider something like ordinal logistic regression, which is tailor made for Likert-style responses like yours. The only real challenge may be having enough data per level to allow the model to do it's job, which you hint as a potential problem. If this indeed is an issue, you could instead consider a Bayesian version which includes priors that force the model to converge. A tutorial for fitting such models, if necessary, can be found here from the creator of the brms package, if the need arises.
